# Dispute over the movement of hot air and cold air

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, air

My neighbour and I share a small window at the end of the corridor in the block of flats where we live.
She often wants to close this window leaving notes on the window saying:

> *"You (me)  are letting the hot air in and the cool air out if you keep opening the window."*

I thought that it was the OPPOSITE in fact, that the air outside is the COOL air (at least at the end of the day, in summer in the UK)

I often open the window at night , or sunset, saying that the air is COOLER after 5pm and therefore letting it in will COOL the interior.

Which of us is correct?

Comment: Why can't you just compare inside air temperatures to outside air temperatures? You just need two thermometers. No one here can tell you when one is hotter/cooler. Only you can figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

To admit cool air into the building at night, you leave the window open. To prevent heat from entering the building during the day, you close that window.

The cooling effect at night, or any time it is cooler outside your flat than inside it,  can be increased by putting a fan in the window opening that actively draws in cooler air from outside and blows it into the corridor. Then at morning, or whenever it gets hot outside, you shut off the fan and close the window.

Comment: Or reverse the fan during the day :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of the window as a channel for the air. Assume that the window is only big enough so that air will flow only in one direction, in or out.

One misconception is to believe that air can flow horizontally just because of temperature difference. It cannot. Warm air can rise and colder air fall in gravity due to density differences. But air must be pushed or pulled to flow horizontally.

When you want to bring cooler air into the room from the outside, you have to pull it into the room. Or, the wind outside has to push it into the room. The opposite is true when you want to push warmer air out of the room.

At the same time that you are pulling or pushing air into/out of the window, you should consider where air is also flowing to make up the loss. You cannot just keep putting air into the room or taking air out of the room without some other air filling in its place.

This companion flow may be happening through the same window. Some air comes in on one side while some air leaves on the other side. Or on the top and bottom parts of the open window. Or in a section there versus a different section somewhere else in the open window. In other words, the window is a two way path. Of course, air is not going to follow ordered traffic rules to “know” which side is in and out flow. It is just a random process.

Ideally, when you want to cool a hot room with cooler air from outside, you would take advantage of one additional fact: colder air will be nearer to the floor. When you open your window at the bottom, also open a comparably sized window at the top. Put a fan in the bottom portion where the cooler yet still hot relative to the outside air is located. Push that air out of the room. The makeup air that flows in the top half of the window will be cooler than the room air. Because it has a higher density, it will want to sink to the floor as it flows into the room. This will create a natural mixing effect to help circulate the air in the room. An even better option is to push hot air out of the room on one side while pulling cooler air into the room from the other side. Failing that, an alternative option is to pull cooler air into the room and have a ceiling fan mix it in the room.

Finally, when you only have the one window and one fan, you should pull the cooler outside air into the room. The warmer air in the room will get pushed to other parts of the house and leave through other exits. You do not want to pull the warmer air in the room and push it out the window. In this case, the make up air to fill the room will come first from the warmer parts of the house. So, the rest of the house will get cooler and your room will be the last part to cool down.